# jquery mobile tapping event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile suggests to use tap events instead of click events, as click adds a delay.

So if I have:

```
   <a id="someID" href="#" onclick="someFunction(); return false">asd </a>
```

how do I change this to inline tapping event?

I could do this:

```
$('#someID').live('tap',function(event) { ... });
```

but don't want to have ID's in my scripts, so prefer to call a function inline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "`inline` tapping event" like, `ontap="someFunction()"`, as `tap` is a `jQuery Mobile` construct.

*Excerpt from jQuery Mobile Source (notice the '**tap**' event):*

```
// add new event shortcuts
$.each(("touchstart touchmove touchend orientationchange throttledresize " +
        "tap taphold swipe swipeleft swiperight scrollstart scrollstop" )
        .split( " " ),
        function( i, name ) { ...
```

For more information:

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.js

Comment: I don't fully understand, but why jMobile doesnt parse let say inline 'ontap' attribute into 'tap' event ? doesnt sound that complicated..

Comment: @StewieGriffin IMHO using `inline event handlers` is *generally shunned* and considered a *bad practice*. So I doubt the jQuery developers would want to support such an API...

Comment: I would prefer to write ontap="doSmth()" inline, which would transform to 'tap' event taking id and a function behind the code. In this case you don't need hardcode IDs in your scripts, no dependencies..  anyway, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @StewieGriffin I agree that having jQuery Mobile parse the document for inline event handlers would be easier (in your scenario) but would be better implemented in browsers as a standard. I wouldn't doubt in the near future if we see these `mobile specific inline event handlers` implemented in mobile browsers...

Comment: Thanks, touchstart & touchend were the ones I needed

Answer (score 4):

Would you like this solution?

HTML:

```
<div ontap="test()">TAP ME</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('[ontap]').each(function(){
    $(this).on("tap", new Function($(this).attr("ontap")));
});
```

Comment: Clever way to add the ability to do tap events but how can it handle dynamic content (inserted in to the DOM after load) which is often dealt with in mobile applications like this?

Comment: @DustinDempsey Please see my answers below. That would work for dynamic added content. :) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind all elements with ontap attribute by:

```
$(document).on('tap', '[ontap]', function(){
     new Function($(this).attr('ontap'))();
});
```

This applies to the whole document, and even dynamically added ones (with ontap attribute ones of course).

And actually you can substitude any attribute name, 'tap', 'tapped', in HTML, and change the 'ontap' to your desired attribute in the script above accordingly.

Hope this helps!